# Two Radio buttons, a textarea and a number box, how to check if textarea is filled when radio1 is Yes and/or 2 is no

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here are the radios and textarea etc.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($canview) > 0) { ?>

      <!-- Questions on return send all this to database then to place where dept. heads can see it-->
            <div id = "returnform" >
            <form action="" method="post">
                <h4>Are any of the item(s) missing?</h4>
                    Yes<input type ="radio" name ="missing" id = "missing1" value = "Yes" required>
                    No<input type ="radio" name ="missing" id = "missing2" value = "No" >
                    <div class = "lossnum">
                    <input type="number" name="lossnum" id = "lossnum" placeholder="0">
                    </div>
                <h4>Was every item put back/plugged in correctly?</h4>
                    Yes<input type ="radio" name ="putback" id = "putback1" value = "Yes" required>
                    No<input type ="radio" name ="putback" id = "putback2" value = "No">
                <div class = "returncomments">  
                <h4>what happened?</h4>
                <textarea name="comments"></textarea> 
                </div>
            </div>
        <input name="item_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item->get_id(); ?>" />
        <h4>Are you sure you want to return these <?php echo $item->get_name(); ?>? </h4>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Return" />
```

right now all i have to change this is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".lossnum").hide();
$(".comments").hide();
$(".returncomments").hide();
$(".commentup").hide();
$("#missing1").click(function () {
    $(".lossnum").show();
    $(".comments").show();
    $(".returncomments").show();

});
$("#missing2").click(function () {
    $(".lossnum").hide();
    if($('#putback2').is(':checked')){
        $(".comments").show();
        $(".returncomments").show();
    }
    else{
        $(".comments").hide();
        $(".returncomments").hide();
    }
});
 $("#putback2").click(function () {
        $(".comments").show();
        $(".returncomments").show();
});
$("#putback1").click(function () {      
    if($('#missing2').is(':checked')){
        $(".comments").hide();
        $(".returncomments").hide();
    }
    else{
        $(".comments").show();
        $(".returncomments").show();
    }
});});
```

this makes it so the textarea opens if 1 is yes and/or 2 is no, the only problem is if you then change the radios to no1/yes2 (which should be the only way the textarea does not show) it stays there, how would i make it so that it only shows up when something other than yes for 1 and/or no for 2 is true, and if that is changed it goes away and if it is not true does not show up.

Next I would like to make is so that when either 1 = Yes or/and 2 = no , the textarea is required to be filled out

**you can for the most part ignore lost num**

[here is a JSfiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/SameB/L7et15du/)

Comment: yes i understand and ignore alot of the php because most of the PHP on there just relates to the rest of the page this code is on and how it interacts with the other things on the page aka that is just a random elseif there is other code on the actual page hahaha

Comment: ok and yeah sorry about the HTML it is a little more understandable in the actual page but yeah changed the jq

Comment: ok there that should work i guess

Comment: well now the textarea disappears thanks! so... do you know how to check if it is filled out only when it is shown?

Comment: If you want to check whether `textarea` is empty or not, you can use something like this: `if ($('textarea').val() != "")`

Comment: it needs to only be when either 1 = yes and/or 2 = no so like where should i put it for only then

Comment: I have shown you how to get `textarea` text/value - now you can use it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemMissing = false
  , itemPluggedIn = true;

function updateCommentsDisplay(itemMissing, itemPluggedIn) {
    if(itemMissing || !itemPluggedIn) {
        $('#comments').show();
    } else {
        $('#comments').hide();
    }
}

$('#nb-of-missing-items-field').hide();
updateCommentsDisplay(itemMissing, itemPluggedIn);

$('#missing input[name="missing-items"]').on('change', function () {
    if(this.value === 'Yes') {
        $('#nb-of-missing-items-field').show();
        itemMissing = true;
    } else {
        $('#nb-of-missing-items-field').hide();
        itemMissing = false;
    }

    updateCommentsDisplay(itemMissing, itemPluggedIn);
});

$('#plugged-in input[name="plugged-in-items"]').on('change', function () {
    if(this.value === 'Yes') {
        itemPluggedIn = true;
    } else {
        itemPluggedIn = false;
    }

    updateCommentsDisplay(itemMissing, itemPluggedIn);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7et15du/7/

Is that what you want to achieve?